# Write PDF report in browser using Jasper service in Grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am using Grails 2.1.1. I am designing report in i-report and to generate it I am using jasper plugin 1.10.0. When I am generating a PDF report it is showing with Adobe Reader but I want to write it in browser. I don't want to use Jasper controller only Jasper service.

Here are my attempts below so far I've understood.

My report generate action

```
def reportDef = new JasperReportDef(name: jasperName, parameters: parameters, fileFormat: JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT)
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"");
response.outputStream << jasperService.generateReport(reportDef).toByteArray()
response.outputStream.flush()
return;
```

Comment: I think it might be about settings in the browser that which file is opened by which application.

By the way which browser do you use?

Comment: I use firefox, chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all due to content type. You have used `response.setContentType("application/pdf");`

Instead of this, you can use
`response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");`